# List of human transcription factors

Tags: database, data-retrieval, human

I'm looking for a list of human transcription factor (TF) genes.

Where can I find a TF database or how can I retrieve this list from other databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lambert et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867418301065?via%3Dihub) (2018, Cell. 172(4):650-665) provide a manually curated list of human TFs at [this website](http://humantfs.ccbr.utoronto.ca/download.php).